# Espresso - Check for specific item in specific fragment of Viewpager

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a ViewPager which contains 3 fragment and each fragment contains a recyclerview.

When page launched -> FragmentA is selected by default and I check for a specific id inside FragmentA and the test is success.

Now i used swifeLeft() to navigate to FragmentB. It worked.

Now I am checking for a specific item in Fragment B. But It throws error as  NoMatchingViewException. In View Hierarchy log, i'm seeing the view hierarchy of FragmentA only. Somehow after swipe the View Hierarchy is not updating.

Did someone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a sleep just after your swipe ? I can help.

Espresso is not able to detect asynchronous work so it might fail because your data is not yet loaded (because of slow network/database etc) when it check the view you want to interact with. So the best solution is to implement IdlingResource in order to make espresso aware of them.
You can take a look at this sample:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/tree/master/ui/espresso/IdlingResourceSample